# Azure Storage Tables: await table.ExecuteAsync(InsertOperation) executes, but never finishes

Tags: c#, .net, azure, async-await, azure-table-storage

Well, my problem is that calling **await table.ExecuteAsync(...)** on Azure Storage Table does insert the requested data, but never finishes (does not return TableResult). Same case with InsertOrUpdate and Update operations. I also tried different tables with different number of properties - same problem.

When I call **table.Execute(...)** - everything works fine for every kind of operation.

Here's my code - simple as that:

Outer call (it is placed in MVC Controller in async action):

```
List<Task<ServiceResult<Boolean?>>> addPostTasks = new List<Task<Common.ServiceResult<bool?>>>();              
foreach (var userStream in userStreams)
{
    Task<ServiceResult<Boolean?>> addPostTask = postsStorageSvc.AddImagePost(...);
    postsAddImagePostTasks.Add(addPostTask);
}
Task.WaitAll(addPostTasks.ToArray());
```

Method called:

```
public async Task<ServiceResult<Boolean?>> AddImagePost(...)
{
ServiceResult<Boolean?> result = new ServiceResult<bool?>(null);
try
{
    PostTableEntity newPost = new PostTableEntity(streamId.ToString(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), creatorId, date, htmlText);              
    TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(newPost);
    //Following line never ends!
    TableResult tableResult = await this._storageTableBootstrapper.Table.ExecuteAsync(insertOperation);                
    //Following line works perfect - but is not ASYNC
    TableResult tableResult = this._storageTableBootstrapper.Table.Execute(insertOperation);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    result.Result = false;
    result.Errors.Add("AzurePostsStorageService Unexpected error: " + ex.Message);
}
return result;
}
```

Comment: How are you calling this method?

Comment: What do you mean? This code block is in async method, I'm updating my question to show the surrounding lines.

Comment: Show the method signature and how you call it. Are you perhaps blocking on it using `Task.Result` or `Task.Wait`?

Comment: I hope it's now more clear how I call it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
Task.WaitAll(addPostTasks.ToArray());
```

Your async method tries to marshal itself back to the ASP.NET synchronization context, which is stuck because you initiated a blocking call using `Task.WaitAll`.

Instead, you'll need to follow the *async all the way* pattern and use `Task.WhenAll`, and `await` on that:

```
await Task.WhenAll(addPostTasks.ToArray);
```

Stephan Cleary elaborates on this in his blog post (which @NedStoyanov added):

> One other important point: an ASP.NET request context is **not** tied to a
>   specific thread (like the UI context is), but it does only **allow one
>   thread in at a time.** This interesting aspect is not officially
>   documented anywhere AFAIK, but it is mentioned in my MSDN article
>   about SynchronizationContext.

Answer (score 4):

This is a classic [deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) caused by this line:

```
Task.WaitAll(addPostTasks.ToArray());
```

try changing it to:

```
await Task.WhenAll(addPostTasks.ToArray());
```

Basically the the `Task.WaitAll` blocks the request thread and it is unable to execute the continuation of the `Tasks` initiated by `await table.ExecuteAsync(...)`. Another alternative is to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` on your internal tasks to avoid switching `SynchronizatonContext`.

```
await table.ExecuteAsync(...).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

You can use `ConfigureAwait(false)` whenever you do not require to switch to the original `SynchronizationContext`. In your case I believe you can do that with all awaits as you are on the server and it shouldn't matter if the code after `await` executes on the thread pool or not.

See this article for more details: msdn.microsoft.com/enus/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: Your answer has the same meaning as the one above, but however you where first Yuval Itzchakov provided more info.

Comment: OK, so to be clear and understand the case better. **Would you advise to use ".ConfigureAwait(false)" on all our async operations which are at the top of execution stack** (like table.ExecuteAsync(...) or even our own async operations/methods)?

Comment: I would do that unless I was in a GUI thread and was using accessing GUI elements after the `await`. See this article for more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are working for an organisation,The problem may be with the proxy settings enabled by your organisation. I had a similar issue and to solve that i used the following steps:

1:Add the following codde in Configure at startup.cs

```
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                var webProxy = new WebProxy(new Uri(Configuration["defaultProxy:proxyaddress"]), BypassOnLocal: false);
                var proxyHttpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
                {
                    Proxy = webProxy,
                    UseProxy = true,
                };
                AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.UseSocketsHttpHandler", false);
```

2: Add the at appsettings.json

```
"defaultProxy": {
    "proxyaddress": "<your IP here>"
  },
```